# value is not displayed in cout

Tags: c++, cout

Value which is located after "v=" is not displayed in code as below.
Let me know how to solve it.

```
while(getline(ifs,line))
    {
        vector<string> strvec=split(line,',');
        for(int l=0;l<strvec.size();l++)
        {
            cout<<"l="<<l<<"value="<<stoi(strvec.at(l))<<endl;
            unsigned char v;
            v=stoi(strvec.at(l));
            File.write((char *)&v, sizeof(char)); 
            cout<<"v="<<v<<endl;
        }           
    }
```

Comment: What's the input you trying to parse ?

Comment: Does `v` contain a printable character code, not something like `0x00`?

Comment: output is as below.
l=122value=32
v=
l=123value=32
v=

Comment: Try `cout<<"v="<<(unsigned)v<<endl;`, you're trying to print integer values (I think) so cast to an integer.

Comment: The input data is csv file as below. 39,39,38,37,33,32,

Comment: 32 is a space so it is naturally not visible

Comment: Thank you john. It is solved by your answer.

Answer (score 2):

"v=" is not displayed in the code because v is unsigned char and cout behavior for unsigned char is to display it's ASCII value and when it is not printable then you will get these type of absurd issues.so either you can declare v as unsigned int or do static_cast as shown in below example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> strvec{std::string("10"),std::string("20")};
  for(int l=0;l<strvec.size();l++)
  {

        std::cout<<"l="<<l<<"value="<<stoi(strvec.at(l))<<std::endl;
        unsigned char v;
        v=stoi(strvec.at(l));
        std::cout<<"v="<<static_cast<unsigned>(v)<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kapli. It is solved by your answer,too. On the other hand, binary file can not be output by adding "File.write((char *)&v, sizeof(char)); . Output file size is 0. Let me know how to solve it.

Comment: Please add more details to your question like where you are opening file and why you are converting this v into char then i can provide better answer